# AttributeError: 'Class' object has no attribute 'rep_call'

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, fixtures

I want to test web-application with the use of Pytest and Selenium. I want to capture screenshots only when a test method fails. I have the following fixture:

```
def driver_init(request):
    # set up driver

    def close_driver():
        driver.quit()

    request.cls.driver = driver
    request.addfinalizer(close_driver)
    yield driver
    if request.node.rep_call.failed:
        try:
            allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name=request.function.__name__, attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
        except:
            pass
```

However when I run this code and the test method fails I receive a following error:

AttributeError: 'Class' object has no attribute 'rep_call'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `rep_call` isn't part of the library. If you copied the example from [Making test result information available in fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/simple.html#making-test-result-information-available-in-fixtures), you have to include the impl of `pytest_runtest_makereport` as this is where `rep_call` is defined.

Comment: I added implementation of `pytest_runtest_makereport` to my code however the same error appears

Comment: I see - most probably you have the fixture scope set to `class`, then.

Comment: Did anybody fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. get_browser method will hold driver implementation for various browsers.

```
@pytest.fixture()
def log_on_failure(request, get_browser):
    driver = get_browser
    yield
    item = request.node
    if item.rep_call.failed:
    allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="Failure",
                  attachment_type=allure.attachment_type.PNG)
```

Use the hookimpl fixture and maintain it in the conftest.py file

```
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True, tryfirst=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)
    return rep
```